# Unable to "fetch" subject matter experts in teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Bug in teams, editing a tag and clicking save gives us an error in red that says:

"Unable to fetch subject matter experts" in teams

Please fix

[image]

Here's the UI:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, we've run out of subject matter experts. Expect re-supply in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @JonH I'm having some trouble reproducing this bug. The error you're seeing happens when the ajax fetch fails (4xx/5xx return status code or failed request). Looking at the traffic logs, I'm seeing the tag edit, but I'm not seeing the followup ajax request hitting the server at all. Can you try again and see if the problem persists? If it *does* still persist, can you detail any potential unique client side setups that might be blocking ajax requests or script execution? Thanks!

Comment: +1 getting this as well. I don't even care about the feature itself, rather that whenever anyone asks or edits a question they get a visual cue that suggests there was an error.

Comment: @BenKelly - It just happened again and it happens at my home pc and work pc two different environments.  Nothing special in terms of client side setups, im on chrome on windows 10, this also happens on safari on a mac.  I can post a screen shot.  This happens only on teams when I edit a tag or add a new tag to a question.

Comment: @JonH the team name is in that screenshot of the dev console. You okay with that?

Comment: @rene that wont matter it does not affect security for that matter.

Comment: @JonH Thanks for the screenshot of the dev console. You're definitely hitting the server there and getting a 404 back... Let me look into this some more today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happy to report that this bug is now fixed!

The issue was that under certain circumstances the client side snippet for Subject Matter Experts (SME) was getting enabled even though SME wasn't enabled for the team (SME is available for Business plans only). This was causing the SME update ajax trigger on tag edits to fire, which then gets validated by the server, which then returns a 404 (remember kids, *always* validate server side!).

I've updated the code so that the client side script is only ever added when SME is enabled for the team.

Comment: And what do I get out of this?